# Batch script fails when run as admin from explorer, but not when run as admin from terminal?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that needs to run as admin. I will be distributing to users so it would be best if they can run it from Windows Explorer.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when run from explorer (right click -> run as admin). It does work when called from a pre-existing admin terminal.

Initially I thought the problem was with the active directory, but I added a "cd /d %~dp0" as the first command. I confirmed through echo that this places them both in the same directory, but it still fails when running from explorer.

The failure occurs when reading an external file in the same directory as the .bat. It pulls empty strings when run from explorer. Here is sample code:

```
rem Make sure active directory is correct (verified that this works)
cd /d %~dp0

rem Load parameters from params.txt
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in ("params.txt") do set %%G=%%H

rem Print params (it's a loop so you can read it when running from expl.)
for /l %%a in (1 1 100000) do echo %DST%
```

Then you just need to make sure params.txt is in same directory as .bat and includes the line "DST=some\directory\name"

Anybody know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Tried with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` ? (Just a wild guess)

Comment: Yep, same result. :/

Comment: Tried with replacing your loop with a simple `echo %DST%` followed by a `pause` to keep the window open?

Comment: That's much simpler! But no, it still doesn't work.

Comment: As an alternative to `usebackq` you can supply the output of a command to `for /f`. For instance, the `type` command: `'type "params.txt"'`. Note that this way you can use quotes as you'd expect without `usebackq`.

Comment: You mentioned that there are "other parameters" in your params.txt file. If you can use a regular expression to identify the lines you're looking for (or at least exclude the problematic ones if any), you could try something like `'type "params.txt"^|findstr /R "="'` (in place of "params.txt"). This expression only grabs the lines that have '=' in them, but obviously you'd be able to make a more useful regex based on the actual content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed about by @nephi12 in his answer if your file name does not have spaces you can remove the quotes, otherwise it thinks the IN clause is a string you want to parse.  If you need to quote your file names then you need to use the `USEBACKQ` option as pointed out by the comments.  Once you use that option your code works just fine.

But I would like to make a point with your code.  If the contents of your params.txt file is:

```
"DST=some\directory\name"
```

Then your `FOR` command can just be this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=" %%G in ("params.txt") do set %%G
```

I am not understanding why you are echoing the `%dst%` variable 100,000 times?

Comment: Thank you, usebackq fixes it. Strange that the problem only occurs when running from file explorer though...As for the params file, it contains other parameters as well, that's why I used that more complicated read command. And the echo was in a loop because I didn't know about the "pause" command.

Comment: @user258887, very doubtful that it was acting differently. Most likely something you were doing.  If you read the help for the `FOR` command it is very clear what happens when things are quoted.

Comment: It was in fact working when run from command line, tried it dozens of times and just tried it again. The bat file had no parameters so nothing that I could do differently -- I just navigated to the directory and typed its name.

Comment: @user258887, sorry to say but that is not correct.  That original line of code will execute the same way regardless if you run it from the command line directly, running the batch file from the command line or double clicking the batch file with your mouse.

Comment: I mean, I understand why you think it theoretically shouldn't happen, but the things that actually happened contradict your theory and were repeated literally dozens of times. Unfortunately real-life results don't always match up with theoretical predictions. If I had video software I could record it and show you, I'm literally testing it again and again right now.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, take away the "s from around `params.txt` as double-quotes means string parsing, while unquoted is a list of files.

Second, try prepending params.txt with `%~pd0\` to ensure the correct path, rather than changing directory.

Comment: Sometimes, you need to quote the filename (e.g. when it contains spaces. In that case, use `for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=1,2" ...` - the usebackq option allows you to put double quotation marks around filenames.

Comment: Thank you Klitos, just adding usebackq fixes it!